# iPhone simulator screenshot in Xcode 3.2.6

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using Xcode 3.2.6. How can I take a screenshot of simulator in any of the 960x640, 960x600, 640x960 or 640x920 formats?

Comment: Are you want to capture the screenshot of the simulator the ViewController?

Comment: For submit app to the appstore...need screenshot of simulator right..please correct me if am wrong am new to this..how can i take screen shot..

Comment: You do not need simulator screenshots but any screenshots. So you may just as well create the screenshots on the device itself (short tap on home and power-off).

Comment: You can also instal the app into your device and that screen shot also upload over the apple site

Comment: other wise you run application into simulator and press sort cut key cmd + s for screen shot of the simulator its work in the xcode 4 but not sure in xcode 3 :-(

Comment: ya that is the problem samuel..And i dont have device right now..device  with one of my team mate not with me now..